# Read file identify string and specific command only

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am collecting data to one file with below script

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "$line"
echo -e "$line-new" >>newfile.txt

done <"file.txt
```

"

new file has below data

```
gl-system-events_1
gl-events_2
gl-system-events_0
gl-events_6
gl-events_1
gl-events_5
gl-system-events_6
gl-system-events_4
gl-events_3
gl-system-events_2
gl-system-events_5
gl-events_0
```

now I want to write script that will read each line in sequence and run specific command for that string

for example if its identify work gl-system-events_2 it should run command A, if its identify gl-events_0 it should run command B, if its identify something else it should run command C

can you help me how I can use if or any other method to archive this.

Regards,
SAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` switch. Something like:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   case $line in
     gl-system-events_2)
        commandA
        ;;
     gl-events_0)
        commandB
        ;;
     *)
        commandC
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thank you White Owl, it helped me to get the desired result. Thank you once again.